# JQuery position() returns the relative position in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used position() to get the absolute position of an element. That worked in Chrome and Firefox but, not in Safari.

In Safari it returns the relative position instead of absolute position.

Comment: Please give more details what you tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it solved by using `offset()` instead of `position()`